# Selenium not able to find element by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am learning selenium by trying to scrape a [particular website](https://www.bigbasket.com). I am trying to access the zipcode input field to try and change the zipcode. This is my code so far

```
try:
    selector = '.btn.hvr-fade'
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)))
    button.click()

    selector = ".btn.btn-default.form-control.ui-select-toggle"
    city_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)))
    city_dropdown.click()

    city = 'Mumbai'
    city = city.title()
    city_path = "//a[@class='ui-select-choices-row-inner']//span[contains(text(), '%s')]" % city
    city_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, city_path)))
    city_element.click()
    time.sleep(1)

    zipcode = 000001
    zipcode_input_path = "//form[@class='ng-valid-editable ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-dirty']//div[@class='form-group area-autocomplete area-select ng-scope']//input[@name='ng- 
    pristine ng-untouched ng-valid-editable ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required']"
            
    zipcode_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, zipcode_input_path)))
    zipcode_input.send_keys(zipcode)

except Exception as e:
    print('scraping could not be completed')
    print(e)
```

From the above code this part fails everytime

```
zipcode_input_path = "//form[@class='ng-valid-editable ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-dirty']//div[@class='form-group area-autocomplete area-select ng-scope']//input[@name='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid-editable ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required']"

zipcode_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, zipcode_input_path)))
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The `XPATH` to the best of my knowledge is correct. But the program fails here. I am also not getting a proper exception message. This is the exception that is returned

```
Message:
```

Please help me out

## EDIT1:

This is the zipcode input box I am trying to target

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `//` in the middle instead of `/`?

Comment: @BurningAlcohol Does it make much of a difference? As far as I know using `//` should search for the required element in the given path right?

Comment: Did you try replacing them with `/`, except for the first leading `//`? And yes they do have a difference, `//` searches from the root while `/` searches from the previous given element

Comment: @BurningAlcohol I tried it just now. I am getting the same error as before

Comment: zipcode needs to be a string.

Comment: @arundeepchohan That doesn't work either

Comment: Look at my answer. I used a much simpler id to target as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this. Change zipcode to a string. As well as getting a simpler id to target.

```
zipcode = '000001'
zipcode_input_path = "areaselect"
        
zipcode_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, zipcode_input_path)))
zipcode_input.send_keys(zipcode)
```

Element to target

```
<input qa="areaInput" typeahead-min-length="3" id="areaselect" ng-change="vm.emptyCheck()" autocomplete="off" name="area" type="text" placeholder="Enter your area / apartment / pincode" ng-model="vm.selectedlocation.query" uib-typeahead="address.label for address in vm.getAreasForCity($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-on-select="vm.onSelect($item)" typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-select-on-blur="true" typeahead-select-on-exact="true" required="" typeahead-no-results="noResultsArea" typeahead-focus-on-select="true" typeahead-wait-ms="200" style="width: 100%; height: 35px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); padding: 4px 15px;" class="ng-pristine ng-valid-editable ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-47-9856">
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed `id` for the element. This works perfectly. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem have a nice day.